# O que significa e como concertar esse erro: EOFError: EOF when reading a line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

O código que eu estava testando funcionava perfeitamente no visual studio, porém, ao submeter em um desses sites parecidos com o `URI`, apareceu esse erro. Sei que é um erro de leitura de linha, mas não consegui entender o motivo de estar funcionando no visual studio e nesse site não funcionar. O código:

```
def primos_gemeos(num):
    valor = False
    for n in range(2, num):
        if num % n == 0:
            break
    else:
        valor = True
    return valor

quantidade = int(input())
lista = []
proxPrimo = None
n = 3
atualPrimo = primos_gemeos(n)
while True:
    proxPrimo = primos_gemeos(n + 2)
    if atualPrimo and proxPrimo:
        lista.append((n, n + 2))
        if len(lista) == quantidade:
            break
    atualPrimo = proxPrimo
    n += 2

print(lista)
```

Comment: Qual será a entrada do programa?

Comment: Pode ser qualquer número inteiro

Comment: Não tem que consertar, o programa tem que tratar quando não tiver mais dados na entrada. Dependendo de onde você testou você tem que fornecer a(s) entrada(s) antes de executar.

Comment: O `else` do if está com endentação correta? Está tentando submeter naqueles sites tipo o UVA online e URI online judge?

Comment: Isso mesmo, tipo esses sites e acredito que o else não seja o problema, pois testei outra abordagem pra verificar se um número é primo

Comment: @Danizavtz o Python possui a estrutura `else` para o `for` também, não somente para o `if`.

Answer (score 4):

Pelo visto você não está tratando a exceção da entrada. Na plataforma da URI é disparada a exceção `EOFError` quando é finalizada a entrada do programa.

```
while True: 
    try: 
        #seu código entra aqui 
        ...
    except EOFError:
        break
```