# Exercício em python 3n +1

Tags: python-3.x, algoritmo

## 3n +1

#### Descrição

Considere o seguinte algoritmo para gerar uma sequência de números. Comece com um inteiro n. Se n for par, divida por 2. Se n for ímpar, multiplique por 3 e some 1. Repita esse processo com o novo valor de n, terminando quando n = 1. Por exemplo, a seguinte sequência de números será gerada quando n é 22:

22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1

Embora ainda não exista uma prova, os matemáticos acreditam que esse algoritmo sempre termina com n=1, para qualquer inteiro n. Bem, para este problema aqui no Huxley, essa propriedade se mantém para qualquer inteiro menor que 1.000.000.

Para uma entrada n, o "tamanho do ciclo" de n é a quantidade de números gerados até o 1 (incluindo o próprio 1). No exemplo acima, o "tamanho do ciclo" de 22 é 16.

Dado dois números i e j, determine o máximo "tamanho do ciclo" dentre todos os números entre i e j, incluindo tanto i quanto j.

#### formato de entrada

A entrada consiste de uma série de pares de inteiros i e j, um par de inteiros por linha. Todos os inteiros serão menores que 1.000.000 e maiores que 0.

Perceba que a entrada só termina quando não houveram mais números. Descubra como fazer o seu programa funcionar nesse caso. Cada linguagem tem uma forma diferente de ler enquanto ainda houver entrada a ser lida.

#### formato de saída

Para cada par de inteiros i e j, imprima i e j na mesma ordem na qual eles aparecem na entrada e então imprima o máximo "tamanho de ciclo" encontrado. Esses 3 números devem ser separados por um espaço, com todos os 3 números em uma linha e sendo uma linha de saída para cada linha da entrada.

Veja o arquivo de exemplo para entender melhor o formato da entrada e da saída.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Meu código:

```
def formula(base):
    numeros = []
    numeros.append(base)

    while base != 1:
        if base % 2 == 0:
            base /= 2
            numeros.append(int(base))
        else:
            base *= 3
            base += 1
            numeros.append(int(base))

    return len(numeros)

def auxiliar(i,j):
    lista = list(range(i,j+1))
    resultados = []

    for elemento in lista:
        resultados.append(formula(elemento))

    return f'{i} {j} {max(resultados)}'


while True:
    entrada = str(input())
    if entrada == '':
        break
    else:
        dados = entrada.split()
        i = int(dados[0])
        j = int(dados[1])

        print(auxiliar(i,j))
```

## O problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: *...a entrada só termina quando não houveram mais números...* no seu programa a entrada termina quando digita um par. Você tem que primeiro ler todos os pares que o testador enviar para depois então começar a calcular. Não vou fazer pois acho que vai o tirar o prazer da jornada em direção a solução.

Comment: `input` já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input())` é redundante e desnecessário, faça apenas `input()` e já terá a string. Sobre o problema do EOF: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/495050/112052

Comment: obrigado @AugustoVasques

Comment: obrigado @hkotsubo